# Quit PyQt4 app when loadFinished complete

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qwebview

I want to close the window after loadFinished complete.
imagine simple code:

```
class Example(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        self.frame.loadFinished.connect(self.some_action)

    def some_action(self):
        # do something here
        # after it's done close app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    url = QUrl("some_website")
    br = Example()
    br.load(url)
    br.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [close()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) on the main window:

```
def some_action(self):
    # do something here
    # after it's done close app
    self.close()
```

Once the last primary window is closed, the application will automatically quit.

You could also just call the application's [quit](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit) function directly:

```
    app.quit()
```

or, more generally:

```
    QCoreApplication.instance().quit()
```